# Plotting multiple lines with different scales on the same graph

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib, data-visualization

What is the most pythonic way to plot multiple lineswith very different scales in the same graph with matplotlib?  I know can create subplots, but I am not really sure they will give me the best visualization.  I don't really care about coloring, legends or any other intricacies at this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only need two scales then you can simple use `twinx` and/or `twiny`

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
x = np.arange(11)
ax.plot(x, 'r')
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(x ** 2, 'g')
plt.draw()
```

I you need more than two see [matplotlib: adding second axes() with transparent background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7761778/matplotlib-adding-second-axes-with-transparent-background) or look into parasitic axes.

Comment: Hi, this is what i am looking for but it is not working with the mpld3.plot() when I try to render the graph on browser. The zoom feature disable and allow only the 1 axis to zoom in-out.