# How to add a second x-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, twiny

I have a very simple question. I need to have a second x-axis on my plot and I want that this axis has a certain number of tics that correspond to certain position of the first axis.

Let's try with an example. Here I am plotting the dark matter mass as a function of the expansion factor, defined as 1/(1+z), that ranges from 0 to 1.

```
semilogy(1/(1+z),mass_acc_massive,'-',label='DM')
xlim(0,1)
ylim(1e8,5e12)
```

I would like to have another x-axis, on the top of my plot, showing the corresponding z for some values of the expansion factor. Is that possible? If yes, how can I have xtics ax

Comment: The functions you are using are not built in to python - I assume you are talking about [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/)?  If so, the question [How do I plot multiple x or y axes in matplotlib?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918028/how-do-i-plot-multiple-x-or-y-axes-in-matplotlib) seems to cover this.

Comment: See http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/two_scales.html

Answer (score 153, accepted):

I'm taking a cue from the comments in @Dhara's answer, it sounds like you want to set a list of `new_tick_locations` by a function from the old x-axis to the new x-axis. The `tick_function` below takes in a numpy array of points, maps them to a new value and formats them:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = ax1.twiny()

X = np.linspace(0,1,1000)
Y = np.cos(X*20)

ax1.plot(X,Y)
ax1.set_xlabel(r"Original x-axis: $X$")

new_tick_locations = np.array([.2, .5, .9])

def tick_function(X):
    V = 1/(1+X)
    return ["%.3f" % z for z in V]

ax2.set_xlim(ax1.get_xlim())
ax2.set_xticks(new_tick_locations)
ax2.set_xticklabels(tick_function(new_tick_locations))
ax2.set_xlabel(r"Modified x-axis: $1/(1+X)$")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: If you want to add a title as well, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12750355/python-matplotlib-figure-title-overlaps-axes-label-when-using-twiny

Comment: @Hooked, any idea if it is possible to this with one of the scales in log scale?

Comment: @tiago I can't check it right now, but does `ax.set_yscale('log')` work?

Comment: Matplotlib has implemented a native way to add a secondary axis. See their example here: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/secondary_axis.html

Comment: Further to @mforbes' answer, if the xlim has been changed for the plot or the original axis, the same limits should be set for the new axis, or else things (e.g. lines and tick marks) start to move around.

Answer (score 34):

You can use twiny to create 2 x-axis scales. For Example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = ax1.twiny()

a = np.cos(2*np.pi*np.linspace(0, 1, 60.))

ax1.plot(range(60), a)
ax2.plot(range(100), np.ones(100)) # Create a dummy plot
ax2.cla()
plt.show()
```

Ref: http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/faq/howto_faq.html#multiple-y-axis-scales

Output:
[image]

Comment: I'm sorry but that's not what I've asked. I don't need to plot to functions on the same plot with different axis. I just need to have a second x-axis, on the top of my plot, ticked in correspondence of some special position on the first x-axis.

Comment: Then just add a dummy 2nd axis with the range you want and clear it. See my edited answer

Comment: Sorry but your code doesn't work. I copied and pasted it and then second x-axis overlap with the first one.

Comment: Attached the output, is this not what you get/want?

Comment: Not really. Taking your example as a reference I would like on the second x-axis these tics: (7,8,99) corresponding to the x-axis position 10, 30, 40. Is that possible in some way?

Answer (score 25):

From matplotlib 3.1 onwards you may use [`ax.secondary_xaxis`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.secondary_xaxis.html)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(1,13, num=301)
y = (np.sin(x)+1.01)*3000

# Define function and its inverse
f = lambda x: 1/(1+x)
g = lambda x: 1/x-1

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.semilogy(x, y, label='DM')

ax2 = ax.secondary_xaxis("top", functions=(f,g))

ax2.set_xlabel("1/(x+1)")
ax.set_xlabel("x")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: When `x=2` then `1/(1+x)` is `0.333...` but your image here shows `0.6` instead. However, upon cutting and pasting your code and running it under matplotlib version 3.5.2 the correct value is shown (and the tick marks are not equally spaced).

Answer (score 19):

If you want your upper axis to be a function of the lower axis tick-values you can do as below. Please note: sometimes `get_xticks()` will have a ticks outside of the visible range, which you have to allow for when converting.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax1.plot(range(5), range(5))

ax1.grid(True)

ax2 = ax1.twiny()
ax2.set_xticks(ax1.get_xticks())
ax2.set_xbound(ax1.get_xbound())
ax2.set_xticklabels([x * 2 for x in ax1.get_xticks()])

title = ax1.set_title("Upper x-axis ticks are lower x-axis ticks doubled!")
title.set_y(1.1)
fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.85)

fig.savefig("1.png")
```

Gives:

[image]

Comment: `ax2.set_xticks(ax1Xs)  `... what is this?

Comment: @jaromrax: that was `ax1.get_xticks()`; the code was written in python3.4 and matplotlib1.4 - matplotlib changed a lot since then.

Answer (score 15):

Answering your question in Dhara's answer comments: "*I would like on the second x-axis these tics: (7,8,99) corresponding to the x-axis position 10, 30, 40. Is that possible in some way?*"
Yes, it is.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

a = np.cos(2*np.pi*np.linspace(0, 1, 60.))
ax1.plot(range(60), a)

ax1.set_xlim(0, 60)
ax1.set_xlabel("x")
ax1.set_ylabel("y")

ax2 = ax1.twiny()
ax2.set_xlabel("x-transformed")
ax2.set_xlim(0, 60)
ax2.set_xticks([10, 30, 40])
ax2.set_xticklabels(['7','8','99'])

plt.show()
```

You'll get:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I'm forced to post this as an answer instead of a comment due to low reputation.
I had a similar problem to Matteo. The difference being that I had no map from my first x-axis to my second x-axis, only the x-values themselves. So I wanted to set the data on my second x-axis directly, not the ticks, however, there is no `axes.set_xdata`. I was able to use Dhara's answer to do this with a modification:

```
ax2.lines = []
```

instead of using:

```
ax2.cla()
```

When in use also cleared my plot from `ax1`.

Comment: This would be a better answer if you provided the code example, instead of just the changes from Dhara's answer.