# Creating 2 x-axes on matplotlib not working

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a graph that has two x-axes on matplotlib. However, it's not behaving how I would expect it to

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
x = np.linspace(-10,10,1000)
y = np.sin(x*np.pi/2)
ax1.plot(x,y)

ax2 = ax1.twiny()
tick_locations = ax1.get_xticks() - 5.
tick_labels = ax1.get_xticks()

ax2.set_xticks(tick_locations[1:])
ax2.set_xticklabels(tick_labels[1:])

plt.show()
```

gives:

[image]

Shouldn't the ax2 labels read: `[ -5.   0.   5.  10.]` at ax1 locations `[-10.  -5.   0.   5.]`

Any ideas why it's stretching them out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit your code:

```
ax2.set_xticks(tick_locations[:])
ax2.set_xticklabels(tick_labels[1:])
```

**edit**:
"Based Carla gama's response to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10514315/how-to-add-a-second-x-axis-in-matplotlib) post it seems you should be able to select any tick locations?"

note that there is a `ax2.set_xlim` in his code, so you can also do this:

```
ax2.set_xlim(tick_locations[0], tick_locations[-1])
ax2.set_xticks(tick_locations[1:]) #1, not 0
ax2.set_xticklabels(tick_labels[1:])
```

I think the key is you should let your ax2 xlim same range as ax1.

Comment: Based Carla gama's response to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10514315/how-to-add-a-second-x-axis-in-matplotlib) it seems you should be able to select any tick locations?

Comment: It looks like `set_xlim` needs to come after `set_xticks`. Other wise `set_xticks` redefines the limits. But you're right, that was the problem.