# How to label the group in grouped barplot in pyplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to do something similar to the following in pyplot where I can label the bars and the group as well. I was able to label the bars but don't know how to label the groups. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Does it make sense to have ["Apples", "Pears", ...] on the x-axis and years as legends rather than on the X axis as well?

Comment: This question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59349185/non-linear-second-axis-in-matplotlib might provide the way forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A default [seaborn barplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html) would create a legend to show the years:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

labels = ['apples', 'bananas', 'coconuts', 'dates', 'elderberries', 'figs', 'grapes']
years = [2017, 2018, 2019]
df = pd.DataFrame({'Fruit': np.tile(labels, len(years)),
                   'Year': np.tile(years, len(labels)),
                   'Amount': np.random.uniform(1.5, 5, len(labels)*len(years))})
ax = sns.barplot(x='Fruit', y='Amount', hue='Year', data=df)
```

[image: default plot]

Placing [`text()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.text.html) using a [`BlendedTransform`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html#blended-transformations) can place new labels at the desired positions. `clip_on=False` is needed to draw outside the main axes area. Vertical lines can be added via `axvline` (these use the `BlendedTransform` by default). New year labels can be put at the position of each bar. The legend and the default xlabel can be removed.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import transforms
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

labels = ['apples', 'bananas', 'coconuts', 'dates', 'elderberries', 'figs', 'grapes']
years = [2017, 2018, 2019]
df = pd.DataFrame({'Fruit': np.tile(labels, len(years)),
                   'Year': np.tile(years, len(labels)),
                   'Amount': np.random.uniform(1.5, 5, len(labels)*len(years))})
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 4))
ax = sns.barplot(x='Fruit', y='Amount', hue='Year', palette='Reds', data=df, ax=ax)
year_pos = np.sort( [p.get_x() + p.get_width()/2  for p in ax.patches])
ax.set_xticks(year_pos)
ax.set_xticklabels(np.tile(years, len(labels)), rotation=30)
ax.get_legend().remove()
ax.set_xlabel('') # remove default xlabel
fruit_pos = year_pos.reshape(-1, len(years)).mean(axis=1)
trans = transforms.blended_transform_factory(ax.transData, ax.transAxes)

for pos, label in zip(fruit_pos, labels):
    ax.text(pos, -0.25,  label, transform=trans, ha='center', va='bottom', color='steelblue', fontsize=14)
for pos in (fruit_pos[:-1] + fruit_pos[1:]) / 2:
    ax.axvline(pos, 0, -0.25, color='steelblue', ls=':' , clip_on=False)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: updated plot]