# How to add second x-axis at the bottom of the first one in matplotlib.?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am refering to the question already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10514315/how-to-add-a-second-x-axis-in-matplotlib).
In this example the users have solved the second axis problem by adding it to the upper part of the graph where it coincide with the title.

Question:
Is it possible to add the second x-axis at the bottom of the first one?

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = ax1.twiny()

X = np.linspace(0,1,1000)
Y = np.cos(X*20)

ax1.plot(X,Y)
ax1.set_xlabel(r"Original x-axis: $X$")

new_tick_locations = np.array([.2, .5, .9])

def tick_function(X):
    V = 1/(1+X)
    return ["%.3f" % z for z in V]

ax2.set_xticks(new_tick_locations)
ax2.set_xticklabels(tick_function(new_tick_locations))
ax2.set_xlabel(r"Modified x-axis: $1/(1+X)$")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As an alternative to the answer from @DizietAsahi, you can use `spines` in a similar way to the `matplotlib` example posted [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/multiple_yaxis_with_spines.html).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = ax1.twiny()

# Add some extra space for the second axis at the bottom
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)

X = np.linspace(0,1,1000)
Y = np.cos(X*20)

ax1.plot(X,Y)
ax1.set_xlabel(r"Original x-axis: $X$")

new_tick_locations = np.array([.2, .5, .9])

def tick_function(X):
    V = 1/(1+X)
    return ["%.3f" % z for z in V]

# Move twinned axis ticks and label from top to bottom
ax2.xaxis.set_ticks_position("bottom")
ax2.xaxis.set_label_position("bottom")

# Offset the twin axis below the host
ax2.spines["bottom"].set_position(("axes", -0.15))

# Turn on the frame for the twin axis, but then hide all 
# but the bottom spine
ax2.set_frame_on(True)
ax2.patch.set_visible(False)

# as @ali14 pointed out, for python3, use this
# for sp in ax2.spines.values():
# and for python2, use this
for sp in ax2.spines.itervalues():
    sp.set_visible(False)
ax2.spines["bottom"].set_visible(True)

ax2.set_xticks(new_tick_locations)
ax2.set_xticklabels(tick_function(new_tick_locations))
ax2.set_xlabel(r"Modified x-axis: $1/(1+X)$")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Works totally correctly. Use `for sp in ax2.spines.values():` for Python 3.x.

Comment: In general you must set the xlim for ax2 manually, so it will be the same as for ax1:
`ax2.set_xlim(ax1.get_xlim())`

Comment: @fanyul. Exact. I think the answer could be completed

Comment: @ttrndavison. See the comment of Fanyul. I had problem to have correctly aligned values when I got `new_ticks_location` from `ax1.get_xticks()` and this comment solved my problem.

Answer (score 7):

I think you have to create a second `Axes` with 0 height (and hide the `yaxis`) to have a second `xaxis` that you can place wherever you like.

for example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_axes((0.1,0.3,0.8,0.6)) # create an Axes with some room below

X = np.linspace(0,1,1000)
Y = np.cos(X*20)

ax1.plot(X,Y)
ax1.set_xlabel(r"Original x-axis: $X$")


# create second Axes. Note the 0.0 height
ax2 = fig.add_axes((0.1,0.1,0.8,0.0))
ax2.yaxis.set_visible(False) # hide the yaxis

new_tick_locations = np.array([.2, .5, .9])

def tick_function(X):
    V = 1/(1+X)
    return ["%.3f" % z for z in V]

ax2.set_xticks(new_tick_locations)
ax2.set_xticklabels(tick_function(new_tick_locations))
ax2.set_xlabel(r"Modified x-axis: $1/(1+X)$")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer to the question, but it took me quite long time until I figured out how to do the same with logscale. There are a bunch of strange behaviours in that case. Here's my code to apply some simple scaling to the original y axis:

```
def set_scaled_y_axis(ax, label1, label2, scale):
    #define the minor and major ticks
    #might give an error for too small or large exponents (e.g. 1e-20 or 1e+20)
    log_ticks_major=[]
    log_ticks_minor=[]
    tick_labels=[]
    for k in range(-15,16,1):
        log_ticks_major.append(10**k)
        tick_labels.append("10$^{"+f"{k}"+"}$")
        for kk in range(2,10):
            log_ticks_minor.append(kk*10**k)

    log_ticks_major=np.array(log_ticks_major)
    log_ticks_minor=np.array(log_ticks_minor)

    #update the original label
    ax.set_ylabel(label2)

    # make a twin axis and set the position
    # to make the same with x axis you need "ax.twiny()" instead
    ax22 = ax.twinx()
    ax22.yaxis.set_ticks_position("left")
    ax22.yaxis.set_label_position("left")
    ax22.spines["left"].set_position(("axes", -0.15))
    
    # draw only the left y axis
    ax22.xaxis.set_visible(False)

    # set the log scale for the 2nd axis
    ax22.set_yscale("log")
    ax22.set_yticks(log_ticks_minor/scale, minor=True) # set minor ticks
    ax22.set_yticks(log_ticks_major/scale) # set normal(/major?) ticks
    ax22.set_yticklabels(tick_labels) #must be after "ax22.set_yticks(log_ticks_major/scale)"
    ax22.tick_params('y', which="minor", labelleft=False) #some "random" minor tick labels would appear
    
    # set the 2nd y axis label
    ax22.set_ylabel(label1)

    # set the limits of the 2nd y axis to be the same as the 1st one
    ax22.set_ylim(ax.get_ylim())
```