# How to hide/remove labels with No Data in a multiple labeled horizontal Bar Chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

Following this question: [Bar Chart with multiple labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43545879/bar-chart-with-multiple-labels).
I tried to replicate the code with a horizontal bar chart. I would like to know how I could remove/hide the labels with No data.

So instead of this: [image: Graph with No Data labels]

looks more like this: [image: Graph only showing the labels with Data]

I attach the code below.

I would appreciate it if someone could steer me in the right direction here.
Thank you in advance.

Cheers

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import ticker
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"DEPARTMENT": ["Accounting", "Administration", "Finance", "Finance", "Human resources", "IT", "Marketing", "R&D"], "DATE": ["June", "June", "July", "June", "June","June","June","June"], "COUNT": [10, 33, 16, 23, 3, 3, 5, 9]}
)

test=pd.pivot_table(df, values='COUNT', index='DATE',columns='DEPARTMENT',
            aggfunc=np.sum)

fig=plt.figure(dpi=300)
ax=test.plot(kind='barh',color=['#4472C4'], legend=False)
ax = plt.gca()
pos = []
for bar in ax.patches:
    pos.append(bar.get_y()+bar.get_height()/2.)

ax.set_yticks(pos,minor=True)
lab = []
for i in range(len(pos)):
    l = test.columns.values[i//len(test.index.values)]
    lab.append(l)

ax.set_yticklabels(lab,minor=True)
ax.tick_params(axis='y', which='major', pad=120, size=0)
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=0)

plt.show()
plt.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited your code to check if each cell value is `nan` when creating the labels.

If the cell value is `nan` then the label value is set to an empty string, if the cell value is not `nan` then the true label is used.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import ticker
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"DEPARTMENT": ["Accounting", "Administration", "Finance", "Finance", "Human resources", "IT", "Marketing", "R&D"], "DATE": ["June", "June", "July", "June", "June","June","June","June"], "COUNT": [10, 33, 16, 23, 3, 3, 5, 9]}
)

test=pd.pivot_table(df, values='COUNT', index='DATE',columns='DEPARTMENT',
            aggfunc=np.sum)

fig=plt.figure(dpi=300)
ax=test.plot(kind='barh',color=['#4472C4'], legend=False)
ax = plt.gca()
pos = []
for bar in ax.patches:
    pos.append(bar.get_y()+bar.get_height()/2.)

ax.set_yticks(pos,minor=True)
lab = []

#EDITED FROM HERE
arr = []
for i in range(len(test.iloc[0].values)):
    arr.append(test.iloc[0].values[i])
    arr.append(test.iloc[1].values[i])

for i in range(len(pos)):
    l = test.columns.values[i//len(test.index.values)]
    val = arr[i]
    if np.isnan(val):
        lab.append("")
    else: 
        lab.append(l)
#TO HERE

ax.set_yticklabels(lab,minor=True)
ax.tick_params(axis='y', which='major', pad=120, size=0)
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=0)

plt.show()
plt.close()
```