# Adding additional x axis labels betwen current labels and graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels

Consider the sample matplotlib gives for grouped bar charts seen here: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.html

With the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


labels = ['G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4', 'G5']
men_means = [20, 34, 30, 35, 27]
women_means = [25, 32, 34, 20, 25]

x = np.arange(len(labels))  # the label locations
width = 0.35  # the width of the bars

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.bar(x - width/2, men_means, width, label='Men')
rects2 = ax.bar(x + width/2, women_means, width, label='Women')
ax.set_ylabel('Scores')
ax.set_title('Scores by group and gender')
ax.set_xticks(x, labels)
ax.legend()

ax.bar_label(rects1, padding=3)
ax.bar_label(rects2, padding=3)

fig.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

they produce the following graph:

[image]

If I wanted to add the x-axis labels "Men" and "Women" in between G1, G2, G3, G4, and G5 and the bars, for each of the 5 measurements, how would I modify this code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bar Chart with multiple labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43545879/bar-chart-with-multiple-labels)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the link @Stef provided, here's a working solution.

The `patches` attribute of your `ax` object contains the bars themselves, which are `matplotlib.patches.Rectangle` objects. If you loop through them, you can then use the `get_x()` and `get_width()` functions to get the x positions and bar widths, respectively. The x positions of each bar are actually the left side, so you need to add half the bar width to get the center.

```python
sublabel_positions = []

# get_x() returns x position of bar's left side
# add 1/2 the bar width via get_width() to get the center
for bar in ax.patches:
    bar_center = (bar.get_x() + bar.get_width() / 2)
    sublabel_positions.append(bar_center)
```

As for the labels, since you defined `rects1` before `rects2` (the men values, then the women values), you want the list of labels to be 5 `Men` strings, followed by 5 `Women` strings:

```python
sublabels = ['Men', 'Men', 'Men', 'Men', 'Men', 'Women', 'Women', 'Women', 'Women', 'Women']

# or you could do:
# sublabels = ['Men'] * 5 + ['Women'] * 5
```

Then you could add the extra x-ticks and labels with a single line shown below. The major x-ticks are your G1 thru G5, so you want to set `minor=True` here.

```python
ax.set_xticks(sublabel_positions, sublabels, minor=True)
```

To make it look better, I ended up specifying a larger figure size, padding the major x-tick labels so they don't overlap, and turning off the major x-ticks, and I get this.

```python
x = np.arange(len(labels))  # the label locations
width = 0.35  # the width of the bars

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
rects1 = ax.bar(x - width/2, men_means, width, label='Men')
rects2 = ax.bar(x + width/2, women_means, width, label='Women')

# Add some text for labels, title and custom x-axis tick labels, etc.
ax.set_ylabel('Scores')
ax.set_title('Scores by group and gender')
ax.set_xticks(x, labels)
ax.legend()

ax.bar_label(rects1, padding=3)
ax.bar_label(rects2, padding=3)

ax.set_xticks(sublabel_positions, sublabels, minor=True)
ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', pad=15)
ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', bottom=False)

fig.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

(I'm sorry I don't have enough reputation to paste images yet)

[Finished barplot with 2 series and stacked major/minor x-tick labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfeIZ.png)

As an aside, if you run `ax.get_xticklabels(minor=True)`, you'll see what I mean about the order of bars being plotted—men first, then women:

```
>>> ax.get_xticklabels(minor=True)

[Text(-0.175, 0, 'Men'),
 Text(0.825, 0, 'Men'),
 Text(1.825, 0, 'Men'),
 Text(2.825, 0, 'Men'),
 Text(3.825, 0, 'Men'),
 Text(0.175, 0, 'Women'),
 Text(1.175, 0, 'Women'),
 Text(2.175, 0, 'Women'),
 Text(3.175, 0, 'Women'),
 Text(4.175, 0, 'Women')]
```

Comment: P.S. To be honest, minor x-ticks and labels are unnecessary in this example. The color of the bars and the legend are what help differentiate what's going on. If you wanted to make this example super obvious, plot the men values in blue and the women values in pink (maybe that's an outdated color scheme these days, but it would be effective). But I digress...