# Python Multiple Bar Charts with Different names for each bar

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, data-science

My question is based on this post: [Bar Chart with multiple labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43545879/bar-chart-with-multiple-labels)

Where the top answers shows us how to make this: [Image from post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hd0eL.png)

However, their labels are "A","B","C","D" for each. I wish to make varying labels.

I.e My bar charts are all in twos so follow an "A","B" format. However, Each label will be completely different. they are as follows. The first two are "project 7", "project 8". Then the next two are "low salary 5 years", "high salary 5 years".

How would one do this?

Comment: As you can see in the question to whose answer you are referring those 'A' ... are from the data that is plotted. Give it a try with your data and if there are specific problems post a minimal reproducible example of your trial code.

Comment: it is great that you have done the research, but this might help both you and those helping you:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example