# R matplot add second X axis

Tags: r, graph, axis-labels

I am a python user relatively new to R. I have the following code that draws this graph:

```
meangf <- c(-0.4183021,-0.4160919, -0.4140347, -0.4121201, -0.4103434, -0.4087048, -0.4058971, -0.4047143, -0.4036499, -0.4026888, -0.4018101, -0.4009911)
meanef <- c(-0.4368967, -0.4361810, -0.4354082, -0.4345807, -0.4337014, -0.4327733, -0.4308227, -0.4298084, -0.4287604, -0.4276822, -0.4265775, -0.4254498)
meanbf <- c(-0.3754438, -0.3808981, -0.3762082, -0.3688898, -0.3645197, -0.3613621, -0.3585380, -0.3562512, -0.3553108, -0.3545954, -0.3540907, -0.3536820)

x <- c(2685, 2754, 2825, 2898, 2973, 3050, 3207, 3287, 3369, 3453, 3539, 3627)

matplot(x, cbind(meangf, meanef, meanbf), col=c(4,2,3), type="l",lty=c(1,1,1) ,xlab="Bandwidth", ylab="Mean", main="Age25_44 Estimate Parameter")
legend("topright",legend=c("Gaussian Fixed", "Expnential Fixed", "Boxcar Fixed"), lty=c(1,1,1),lwd=2
,col=c(4,2,3),
ncol=3,bty="n",cex=0.8,
text.col=c(4,2,3),inset=0.01)
```

[image]

I would like to add a second x-axis on top of the graph such as

```
 x2 <- c(20000, 22000, 24000, 26000, 28000, 30000, 32000, 34000, 36000, 38000, 40000, 42000)
```

How can I do that?

EDIT:

The solution I,d like is something similar to this question [How to add a second x-axis in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10514315/how-to-add-a-second-x-axis-in-matplotlib)

Comment: What is the mathematical relationship between x2 & x?

Comment: there is not mathematical relation. the blue and red line use x while the green line uses x2

Comment: Well, the second x-axis has to be plotted in relation to the first, right? So how would you propose aligning them?

Comment: I misunderstood the question. see `?axis`

Comment: I would align the minimum of the x with the minimum of x2 and so on. Does it male sense?

Comment: In principle, yes, but in practice not so much. E.g., what is the plotted minimum of x right now? You could manually set a min and max for x and x2 to solve that problem; if you did, what would you set it to?

Comment: x (min: 2685, max: 3627), x2(min: 20000, max: 42000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `axis()`.

```
where = seq(from=min(x), to=max(x), length.out=length(x2))
axis(1, where, labels=x2, padj=2)
```

`padj` will let you place the axis down further

Comment: I am sorry it is not clear to me. Could you provide a full example please?

Comment: I would you combine this into my code. Sorry I,m a python user new to R

Comment: Just run these commands right after running your code and see what they do.

Comment: also you could add `col.ticks='green'` to make this axis match your line color if you want.

Comment: Super!! exactly what I needed