# Second plot axis with different units on same data in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'd like to add a second y-axis to my plot `plt.plot([1,2,4])` on the right side, which should be aligned with the left axis, but in different units which can be calculated.

For example a scaling to 1. So effectively the left y-axis will be [1,2,3,4] and the right should be [0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0] and properly aligned.

How can I do that in matplotlib?

(the twin axis example seems to handle a different use-case where you have un-aligned axes on different data)

Comment: a quick workaround would be to use `twiny` and manually provide limits for that axis that are based on the limits of the left-hand side y-axis ... but I'm aware that this is not the solution you are looking for...

Comment: Adapt the gallery's celsius-or-fahrenheit example: http://matplotlib.org/examples/subplots_axes_and_figures/fahrenheit_celsius_scales.html

Comment: @cphlewis: Thanks. That works. I just had to be careful not to use `plt.` thereafter, or it gets confused.

Comment: Yes, this crosses the boundary from the pyplot/matlab style to where OO style works better -- [nice summary](http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html?highlight=plt%20style#coding-styles)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a second x-axis in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10514315/how-to-add-a-second-x-axis-in-matplotlib)

Comment: PSA: The example above will not work if the two axes being plotted do not have a linear relationship :(

Answer (score 7):

This was answered in a link in the comments, but I'd like to add the solution here in case that link breaks. Basically you make a twin axis, and use `callbacks.connect` to make sure the new axis updates whenever the original does. As such, the connection code needs to go before the plotting commands. Using the OP's example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1,2,3,4]

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

# add second axis with different units, update it whenever ax1 changes
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

def convert_ax2(ax1):
    y1, y2 = ax1.get_ylim()
    ax2.set_ylim(y1/max(x), y2/max(x))
    ax2.figure.canvas.draw()    

ax1.callbacks.connect("ylim_changed", convert_ax2)   

ax1.plot(x)
```

[image: plot with two axes]