# matplotlib: histogram plot with 2 xticks?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a pandas series `X` as X1, X2, ... Xn

I normalize the `X` series to have a new `Y` series with `mean=0` and `std=1`.

I want to plot the `histogram` of `X` with 2 `xticks`, one is original values and the other represented normalized values.

How could I do that with matplotlib?

**Update**:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.random.randint (0,100,1000)

y = (x- np.mean(x))/np.std(x)
```

Now I want to plot the histogram of `y`, but also show the original values (`x`), not only values of `y`.

Comment: Share your data series sufficient enough to reproduce/plot something. Currently we have no data to plot and it's all speculative.

Comment: Can you show an example of what the plot should look like? Preferably you should also include a [mcve]

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/examples/api/two_scales.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a second x-axis in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10514315/how-to-add-a-second-x-axis-in-matplotlib)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example, with a second scaled top axis:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Some data
x = 12 + 3*np.random.randn(1000)
x_normed = (x - np.mean(x))/np.std(x)

# Graph
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

ax1.hist(x_normed, bins=20)

x1_lim = np.array(ax1.get_xlim())
x2_lim = x1_lim*np.std(x) + np.mean(x)

ax2 = ax1.twiny()
ax2.set_xlim(x2_lim)

ax1.set_ylabel('count')
ax1.set_xlabel('normed x', color='k')
ax2.set_xlabel('x', color='k');
```

Doing the other way around is I think better:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Some data
x = 12 + 3*np.random.randn(1000)

# Graph
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

ax1.hist(x, bins=20)

x1_lim = np.array(ax1.get_xlim())
x2_lim = (x1_lim - np.mean(x))/np.std(x)

ax2 = ax1.twiny()
ax2.set_xlim(x2_lim)

ax1.set_ylabel('count')
ax1.set_xlabel('x', color='k')
ax2.set_xlabel('x normed', color='k');
```

which gives:

[image: hist_with_multiple_axis]